# get $_post in laravel from javascript $.post

Tags: php, laravel, post, .post

I have an html with a script that is like so (btw, HAVe to use old fashioned post in my html for reasons)...

```
@extends('layout')
// ... includes for jquery and ajax
<script>
var theVariableINeedInLaravel = "SomeInterestingStringI'mSure"; // in reality, this is a stringify.
$.post ("foo", function(theVariableINeedInLaravel) {
}
</script>
@stop
```

Then in routes.php...

```
<?php
Route::post('foo', 'ThatOneController@getValue');
?>
```

Then, in the related controller....
ThatOneController.php

```
class ThatOneController extends \BaseController{
    public function getValue(){
    error_log(print_r($_POST,true)); // returns nothing.
    error_log(print_r(input::all()); // returns nothing.
}
```

}

Or, an alternate version of the function...

```
public function getValue(Request $request){
error_log(print_r($request->all()); // returns nothing.

}
```

None of them seem to work. How can I get my post variable?

Comment: By the way, I know hypothetically `$value = input::get('someDesignatorname')`; should get me my passed variable, but the `$.post` doesn't set a name for the array value meaning a non-keyed array... so the ::get won't get me out of the mess.

Comment: I saw someone rated my question down, could I get an explanation why?

Comment: I did not, but your code is incomplete.

Comment: Pretty much all the relevant code was there.. I added headers... what do you feel is missing?

Comment: is data passed via js?

Comment: Yep, I tested it and it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
use Request;
class ThatOneController extends \BaseController{

public function getValue(){
  print_r(Request::all());
}
```

Comment: I found this out the hard way before I noticed your response, but it's better than original solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that even if $_post isn't always accessible from inside a controller function, it *is* directly accessible from Routes. It's a bit hacky, and "not the laravel way" but you can use $_post in routes to get and pass into other variables to get back into the normal flow.

Comment: That is not true, `$_POST` is global and can be accessed from anywhere. can you post your full js ?

Comment: I found out the hard way, but laravel actually can sometimes clear out $_POST before you get to the target page, so it's no longer accessible to internal pages, and you have to go through ::all to get at it. I also found Request::all got me my data as well if $_POST was returning empty, despite javascript passing by $.post